# What is the highest number of genes expressed under one T7 promoter?

Tags: molecular-genetics, synthetic-biology, t7-promoter

What is the highest number of genes expressed under one T7 promoter? Also, what is the longest polycistronic mRNA? I am interested in the context of heterologously expressing biosynthetic gene clusters in E. coli.

Comment: does T2A/P2A peptides work for your case?

Comment: @aaaaaa Not really, since I would like to avoid adding extra sequence to the coding region.